# Excel/ Asignar valor a celda dependiendo del valor de otra

Tags: excel, funciones, vba, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Buen día!!!
Estoy intentando ganar tiempo con la generación de documentos acelerando las tareas repetitivas. En este caso tengo 3 celdas dependientes. Quiero llenar una y que con esa pista tome los valores necesarios para las otras 2.

En D3 introduzco el valor de P4 de forma manual. Necesito que E2 y E7 entonces, tomen el valor de Q4 y M4. respectivamente y cuando el valor de D3 sea por ejemplo, 4788 (P6), E2 y E7 tomen los valores de Q6 y M6 respectivamente.

[image: captura de hoja de excel. donde E2 y E 7 dependen de D3]

Answer (score 1):

solucion

=BUSCARV(D3;M4:N21;2; FALSO)

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Answer (score -1):

adjunto propuesta:

```
=FLATTEN( QUERY(M4:Q11;"select Q, M where P=" & D3 ;0))
```

El valor M4 retorna el valor de la orden y extracción, la función 'FLATEEN' lo muestra en columna.

Saludos

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).